# Creating and calling PL/SQL functions

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I'm new to PL/SQL. It's been on fine until now that is. 
I've the query this query which works fine.

```
declare
rec employees_practice%rowtype;
sam taxObligations%rowtype;
socialsecurity number;
rentallowance number;
transportation number;
taxableincome number;
incometaxliability number;
netpay number;
total number;
totaldeductions number;

    begin
    for rec in (select * from employees_practice)
    loop
    socialsecurity:=(5.5/100)*(rec.salary);
    rentallowance:=(20/100)*(rec.salary);
    if(rec.Category='S') 
    then transportation:= 150; 
    else transportation:=100;
    end if;

taxableincome:=rec.Salary-socialsecurity+rentallowance+transportation;

for sam in (select * from taxObligations) 
loop
if(taxableincome between sam.Minincome and sam.Maxincome)
then incometaxliability:= sam.MinimumBracketTax + (taxableincome-sam.Minincome)*(sam.TaxBracketRate/100);
else incometaxliability:=null;
end if;
end loop;
netpay:= taxableincome-incometaxliability;
total:= rec.Salary + rentallowance + transportation;

totaldeductions:=socialsecurity + incometaxliability;

-- Here, I used DBMS.... to give an output in different format.

end loop; 
end;
```

I now want to create a function that encompasses the above code so I can call it with a single SQL or PL/SQL Query. It's been a headache for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a [pipelined function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:19481671347143):

first you'll need a table type:

```
create or replace type result_tab as table of varchar2(32767);
```

Then, make your code a pipelined function:

```
create or replace function your_func return result_tab PIPELINED is

rec employees_practice%rowtype;
sam taxObligations%rowtype;
socialsecurity number;
rentallowance number;
transportation number;
taxableincome number;
incometaxliability number;
netpay number;
total number;
totaldeductions number;

    begin
    for rec in (select * from employees_practice)
    loop
    socialsecurity:=(5.5/100)*(rec.salary);
    rentallowance:=(20/100)*(rec.salary);
    if(rec.Category='S') 
    then transportation:= 150; 
    else transportation:=100;
    end if;

taxableincome:=rec.Salary-socialsecurity+rentallowance+transportation;

for sam in (select * from taxObligations) 
loop
if(taxableincome between sam.Minincome and sam.Maxincome)
then incometaxliability:= sam.MinimumBracketTax + (taxableincome-sam.Minincome)*(sam.TaxBracketRate/100);
else incometaxliability:=null;
end if;
end loop;
netpay:= taxableincome-incometaxliability;
total:= rec.Salary + rentallowance + transportation;

totaldeductions:=socialsecurity + incometaxliability;

-- Here, I used PIPE ROW() to give an output in different format.
pipe row('what ever you had in your dbms_output command');

end loop; 

return;

end your_func;
```

Now, you can call / query it like this:

```
select * from table(your_func)
```

Comment: I tried it and got this error.

    Error at line 0: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

Comment: radashk, that's what I've been trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working now, try doing it all in a stored FUNCTION with a CURSOR as IN parameter to return a NUMBER. Learn about variable types and cursors. 
The Oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm) should be enough for you to do it yourself.

After that, if you encounter problems with your code post it here and you certainly will be helped.